# PHP - Check for distinct filename on file upload

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP.  I hate to have to ask questions, because I'm sure this is documented somewhere, but after looking for a while, I just cannot seem to put two and two together.

I have a program that will allow multiple images to be uploaded to an item within the database.  Basically, for each item in the database, there might be multiple image uploads.

Example:

- Item: Xbox 360

Images:

- Xbox360.jpg
- side.jpg
- front.jpg

The image and item information is all stored in the database (MySQL), but the images are stored within the filesystem, and the database points to the URL of the image(s) in the filesystem.

The problem I'm having is that everything works as expected, except it allows duplicate image names to be written to the database.  It doesn't allow duplicate images to be written to the filesystem, which I'm happy with.  I want to make sure that the name of an image is only added once to the database.  If the image name is a duplicate to another, it needs to not write to the database.

add_db.php:

```
$uniqueDir = uniqid();
$directory = "img/$uniqueDir/";

db_addItem($id_category, $name, $cost, $description, $qty, $directory); //Adds to the `items` table

foreach ($_FILES['i_file']['name'] as $filename) { 
    if ($filename != '' && $filename != 'No file chosen') {
        //I think above is where I check for unique image names
        $url = "img/$uniqueDir/$filename";
        db_addImg($url, $filename); //Adds to the `img` table
        $item_picsID = get_item_PicsID($filename, $url);
        $itemID = get_itemID($directory);
        db_insertImg($itemID, $item_picsID);
    }
}
addFilesystem($directory); //Writes image(s) to filesystem

function db_addImg($url, $filename) {
    include 'mysql_login_pdo.php';

    // Create the SQL query
    $query = "INSERT INTO img (`name`, `url`) VALUES(:filename, :url)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':filename' => $filename,
        ':url' => $url
    ));
}

function db_insertImg($itemID, $item_picsID) {
    include 'mysql_login_pdo.php';

    // Create the SQL query
    $query = "INSERT INTO `item_pics` (`item_id`, `img_id`) VALUES(:itemID, :item_picsID)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':itemID' => $itemID,
        ':item_picsID' => $item_picsID
    ));
    $db = null;
    return;
}
```

Everything works, except it will write duplicate image names to the database.  I want the image names to be distinct.  I also don't want to rename the images (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an `UNIQUE` index on the `name` column in `img` table, and then use slightly modified `INSERT` statement in your `db_addImg` function:

```
function db_addImg($url, $filename) {
    //...
    $query = "INSERT INGORE INTO img (`name`, `url`) VALUES(:filename, :url)";
    //...
}
```

It will quietly cancel any insert where the is a `UNIQUE` key collision, which will end up in distinct filenames across your `img` table.

Comment: I think I follow your thought pattern here.  I didn't know about the "INSERT IGNORE" option within MySQL, so I'll read up on that.  My guess is it will ignore the query if the `name` column is set to UNIQUE and it matches a record already in the database?  (If name is not unique, do not write name and url to table)

Comment: You're right. Normal `INSERT` would produce a constraint violation error in this situation. Using `INSERT INGORE` quietly cancels the whole query if it's about to produce this error.

Comment: Thanks, my friend.  If I had enough rep to upvote you, I would :)

Comment: Quick question: If I was to set `name` to unique, I would not be able to store images with the same name in different URLs.  Is there a way to make sure that the combination of columns `name` and `url` produce a unique value, instead of just the `name` column?

Comment: You can add both columns to the unique index, so only their combitation is forced to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a filename based on the primary key from the `img` table as you're guaranteed it's unique.

Otherwise, you'll need to *guess* a unique filename with some type of hashing and then check the file system. All of which can be expensive operations.

Looks like you are using PDO, so the static method [`lastInsertId`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) will get the last insert id (primary key).

For example:

```
// after your insert to img
$filename = 'img' . $db->lastInsertId() . $extension;
```

This will require changing the `img` table slightly. But you're better off storing meta data (file type, size, etc) in this table as opposed to the file location (as that can change).

Comment: Dude, thanks for the link.  I'm still learning PDO, so I haven't come across `lastInsertId` yet.  Thanks for that info!

Answer (score 0):

I think better to use `hash` value of your `url` as the `primary key`. Be cause string searching is much slower as `int`.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are suggesting.  Hash is a foreign word to me, except for passwords, so if you have a link I can read up on, I'd majorly appreciate it.  My MySQL table that handles the `url` had the following columns: 'id', 'url'.  I'm assuming you're telling me to use the 'id' as opposed to the 'url'?